# Install old Plugin in last Eclipse or JBoss Dev Studio

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jdo, jboss-developer-studio

I'm trying to install old JPox plugin in my Jboss Dev Studio 9 (note, I'm working in legacy project, so I want to install the old), but it doesn't seem to work.

I've clicked through Help, Install New Software, then clicked add, then clicked archive, and then browsed to org.jpox.ide.eclipse_1.1.3.jar.

However, it informs me that "No software site found at jar:file:/Users/.../org.jpox.ide.eclipse_1.1.3.jar!/. Do you wish to edit the location?"

Note, I have tried to extract and load the jpox-eclipse-plugin.jar and after extract the HOME_JBOSS folder\studio\plugins\org.jpox.ide.eclipse_1.1.3

You can get JPox in [JPox link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpox/files/jpox-eclipse/1.1.3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install New Software can only be used for things that are packaged as a 'software site'.

The jar you have downloaded is just a single plugin. Copy the plugin to the 'dropins' directory in your Eclipse installation and restart Eclipse to install it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer greg-449, solved. Best regards!

Comment: Note that use of a dropins directory is discouraged... but sometimes it's the only way to deal with old plugins when you don't have time/desire to turn those old plugins/features into a property p2 repo, then perform a real installation. Here's a script to convert a folder w/ plugins/features into a proper p2 repo: https://gist.github.com/nickboldt/3ee72723f8d9b828139825f715d8f066